# scroll to a link and activate it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a website in two column. On the left side there are alls link, on the other side there is the content. When you click on a link the content goes up, and the link also align itself.
[You can test it here](https://jsfiddle.net/yagayente/tkvtr2e3/1/) 
I'm searching for a way to implement a button on the bottom of the left side, that allow to scroll to the top of the document in a special way : 
il will to activate the first link on top (and scroll to it) and in the same time align the correspondent article of the right side. So far the alignment system is working, except for this link, see the code i'm trying to add bellow.

```
   $('.cd-top').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $container = $('.menu-content:first'),
        $desc = $('.menu-content:first');

            $desc.slideDown('100', function() {
                $("#scrollingaside").scrollTo( $container, 500, {offset: { top:-1 } } );//    la hauteur d'alignement c'est ici !
                $("#scrollingontheright").scrollTo( $("#" + $container.attr('data-id')), 1500);  
            });
        }
    });
    $('.article').bind('click', function() {
        var idproj = $(this).find('span:first').attr('id');
        $('.menu-content[data-id="' + idproj + '"]').find('.cd-top').trigger('click');
    });
```

Comment: Link of the Fiddle has been corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// use on() instead of bind

```
$('.expander').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $container = $(this).parents('.menu-content:first'),
    $desc = $(this).parents('.menu-content');
// newly added
    $('.expander').parents(".current").removeClass('current');
    if($container.hasClass('current') == false) {

        var others = $('.current');
        $container.addClass('current');

        $desc.slideDown('100', function() {
            $("#scrollingaside").scrollTo( $container, 500, {offset: { top:-1 } } );//    la hauteur d'alignement c'est ici !
            $("#scrollingontheright").scrollTo( $("#" + $container.attr('data-id')), 1500);  
        });
    }
});
$('.article').bind('click', function() {
    var idproj = $(this).find('span:first').attr('id');
    $('.menu-content[data-id="' + idproj + '"]').find('.expander').trigger('click');
});
**// new code**
 $(".cd-top").on("click",function(){
$('.expander:first').trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: Seems to work BUT only if I click once on that link. If I click twice, the button seems not active. See here = https://jsfiddle.net/yagayente/rjw5r7qL/2/ Any idea ?

Comment: $(this).parents(".current").removeClass('current'); i have added this line check once it should work now
Note: even the links also are not working on second click resolved now

Comment: Ok. Almost there ! :)  the scroll work now... But : it seems like "current" class now remain on every link clicked instead of leaving when you change of link. see that problem here : https://jsfiddle.net/yagayente/tkvtr2e3/2/ — I made a css for the ".current" to see

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can just attach a click handler to that button and trigger ("forward") a click event on the top most link from the menu:

```
   $('#top').click(function() {
     $('.menu a')[0].click()
   })
```

The selector '.menu a' must be modified to target the correct link.

Comment: didn't succeed at making it work yet.. https://jsfiddle.net/yagayente/rjw5r7qL/1/

Comment: Humm. Not working. Or don't know how to deal with that. Anyone ?